# Change view of contacts in salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, page-layout, design

I want to add a button to edit or create a custom object, that I already created and configure, in my Salesforce1.

I expect something like that (with the buttons "Edit" and the menu next to:
[image]

(Image from here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=compact_layout_create.htm&language=es)

But I can't find where to configure it. I tried modifying the compact layout, but I can't found it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a new action to either the global actions or the object specific actions. You should be able to find this under Accounts > Buttons, Links, and Actions. [Here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_global_actions.htm&language=en_US) will give you some assistance on creating a new action. Once the action is made, you will be able to edit the page layout of the object, and add the action to the publisher layout.